# How to tell when I logged in?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, event-viewer

I want to find out when I logged into my machine on a given day. In the Event Viewer, Windows Logs, Application, I see entries like:

Level        Date and Time         Source          Event Id Task Category
Information 2/28/2018 12:33:31 AM Security Center 15 None

How do I find a login event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to turn on "Audit logon events"

- Open "Local Security Policy"
- Navigate to:

> Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local
>   Policies\Audit Policy

- Modify "Audit account logon events"
- Enable "Success"
- Enable "Failure"

Now reboot and check your logs again.

SOURCE: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976367.aspx